# Error 404 installing taildwind css - taildwindcss@latest is not in npm registry

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, vite

Hello I just started a personal project with react using **vite** with the command `npm create vite@latest`, and everything went smoothly, but when I wanted to install taildwind css this happens:

I did the following command `npm install -D taildwindcss postcss autoprefixer` following the official get started documentation of tailwindcss
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

And the console gives me this error:

[image]

I have tried omitting the -D from the command in case it had something to do with it, it is not the case, it happens in the same way.

It is not the first time I use taildwind, I have always started my projects in the same way, this error is the first time it happens to me, so I don't know what is certainly happening.

How could I solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

This solves the problem, source: https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn/issues/65

However, having to force me to use the latest version of a package can often bring problems, I am not convinced by the solution, but it is a solution.